# Upload image with transparent background to azure blob displays the image with black background

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
                {

                    var bytesImage = Utilities.ImageToByteArray(img, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    using (MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(bytesImage))
                    {
                        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memstr);
                    }

                }
            }
```

the code above is used to upload file to blob storage the image has transparent like this

[image]

after uploading, the result contain black background like this

[image: After_Upload_To_blob_storage]

Comment: What does the method `Utilities.ImageToByteArray` do? What is the original image format?

Comment: well, you converted your picture to `Jpg` - a format that does not support transparency. nothing you can do there, except pick another format.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks for your help, i changed the format to the format of the image which i try to upload "png in my case" and it woks fine.

Comment: Can you post that as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow  @Franz Gleichmann Answer,
"Well, you converted your picture to Jpg - a format that does not support transparency. nothing you can do there, except pick another format"